# Add "more" button/link to end of the grid list

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have grouped GridView.

For each letter I`m displaying 10 signs (Sign). After displaing 10 I want to add "more" link/button. For example button the has diffrent color and has special onclick event.

How can I do this for each group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you want to develop a Windows 8 App. There is not need for a "more"-button.

Take a look at the Grip-App-Template. It is using the grid group header to navigate to the group. This is the recommended way.

Use the content as navigation and not a button.

I really recommend you to take a look at the design guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770552

Comment: I've got this design from company recomended by Microsoft for us and there is link at the end of the list. I'm just implementing this so I'm not thinking is this correct way or not. But thanks for the tip. You way is much easier and I will get it for discussion :)

Comment: thanks this is much better. First of all it doesn`t need so much work. Secondly it`s more intuitive

Comment: Yes and it is what Microsoft wants. I tried to submit some apps to the store and they failed the certification cause of such little things. :)

Comment: As Jerry Nixon said below, guidelines are guidelines, and real life is real life. Endless scrolling is also good, but not for all scenarios. So, if you really need "add more" button, check Jerry's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12643002/883738

Answer (score 2):

You should

1. Add another item of a different type at the end of each group of items you bind to the GridView with ItemsSource
2. Write a DataTemplateSelector implementation that will use a different DataTemplate for regular items and the last item
3. Set GridView.ItemTemplateSelector to your custom DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: but if I`m binding `List<Sign> items` I should change it to `List<object> items` ? But what object should I add ?

Comment: Right, you would use List<object> and put in something like SignViewMore in the list and implement SignViewMore so that when its corresponding DataTemplate gets clicked or tapped - you get more items. Also - if you are planning on adding more items in the GridView when that item gets tapped (which is not recommended) - you would need to use an ObservableCollection instead of the List so the view updates when you do add more items to the list.

Answer (score 2):

The design guidelines says: Users can tap on the section label to drill in to the corresponding page for that section. Provide a visual cue, like View all (x), to indicate to users that there are more items in this section that what is shown in the hub. Using this pattern avoids the need to use a tile space or place a link within the content.

However, I want to be honest that some developers and designers do not feel that this is a sufficient enough affordance to help users intuitively navigate their applications. In the end, the guidelines are not the rules. They are the guidelines. Adding a "view all" tile to your applications is your decision. If it helps your app, do whatever helps.

And if you do then DataTemplateSelector is the way you change the template displayed. In order for this to work, you would need to include the index of the items in your list so that you know where to put this final tile. This keeps you from having to mix data tyles as Filip suggested (a valid but heavy-lifting solution). Anyway, it's up to you and it's easy.

Comment: thank you for your response. I`m aware that guidlines are just guidlines not rules :) Bot I want to take from them a lesson and combine my solution (more button) with navigation in title of group by putting more button in the title. It is much easier to achive and I get - what in my opinion - is the best for user